# How can I send edits to my blog programmaticly?

Tags: api, automation

I have started a very simple wordpress blog for a hockey pool I run. The site is located at: http://thekeeperpool.wordpress.com/

I manage the actual stats counting and player movement using a local application I made in c#. I have written some logic to output the HTML needed for the body of each persons team page. (e.g. http://thekeeperpool.wordpress.com/andrews-team/) Right now, I need to open up each of the 6 team pages, press the edit button to bring up the page's html, and then paste then new version of the body HTML in. I am looking for a way to automate this.

I have looked at the wordpress REST API, and it seems like it has the features I would need (http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1/post/sites/%24site/posts/%24post_ID/) but I have no idea how to use this API. Am I headed in the right direction? How do I use this API in a script running on my local machine to access my blog, hosted by wordpress?

Comment: I'm afraid your question is off-topic, according to the [FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq). This site is for the self-hosted version of WordPress, not WordPress.com.

Comment: WordPress.com offers the same XML-RPC API like regular WordPress installations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [XML-RPC API](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API) to post to your blog. Windows Live Writer and other apps are using that too. I am not very familiar with that API, so I have no good examples. But you should [find enough](http://www.google.com/cse?cx=008094839757605916882%3af6pwe-gmjka&ie=UTF-8&q=xml%20rpc#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=xml%20rpc&gsc.page=1) with the keyword. There are also many plugins with sample code.

Comment: This is the solution for me. Still looking in to it but there seems to be enough material out there.